# How to build a solution or run an asp.net project from a folder containing .aspx.cs, .cs, .config and .css files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

NET and C#. I have a fair understanding of executing a web app built on wamp/lamp framework. However here I have the following files for the project (mentioned below). I am unable to figure out how to get the web app running on my local machine.

With wamp/lamp, all we need to do is put the `.php` file in `www` root folder and it runs. However here I am clueless on how to proceed.

I have got the IIS running on my local.

The below files are located in this path:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\code

aboutus.aspx
aboutus.aspx.cs
Accountpage.aspx
Accountpage.aspx.cs
addphotos.aspx
addphotos.aspx.cs
chatid.aspx
chatid.aspx.cs
chatroom.aspx
chatroom.aspx.cs
composemail.aspx
composemail.aspx.cs
confirm.aspx
confirm.aspx.cs
confirmok.aspx
confirmok.aspx.cs
createaccount.aspx
createaccount.aspx.cs
Default2.aspx
Default2.aspx.cs
eo_web.ashx
Faq.aspx
Faq.aspx.cs
file manager.aspx
file manager.aspx.cs
homepage.aspx
homepage.aspx.cs
inbox.aspx
inbox.aspx.cs
login.aspx
login.aspx.cs
registration.aspx
registration.aspx.cs
send sms.aspx
send sms.aspx.cs
StyleSheet.css
uploadfile.aspx
uploadfile.aspx.cs
useraccount.aspx
useraccount.aspx.cs
video.aspx
video.aspx.cs
web.config
```

But when I point my browser to

```
http://localhost/Project/code
```

I get this error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>      Notification      BeginRequest
>      Handler       Not yet determined
>      Error Code    0x800700b7
>      Config Error      There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
>      Config File       \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\Code\web.config
>      Requested URL     http://localhost:80/Project/Code
>      Physical Path     C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\Code
>      Logon Method      Not yet determined
>      Logon User    Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:
>   13:           
>   14:               
>   15:
>
> More Information:
>   This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Please help me get started with this.

Comment: your web.config file is wrong: fix this error `There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined`

Comment: Actually the link "http://localhost/Project/code" is not correct. You should go to IIS -> add new web site -> link your http://localhost:80 (or other port) with your web site directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\code"